# sort two dimensional array by descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a two-dimensional array given from a db data in a custom order.

To sort the main array I'm using this:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a[0] <=> $b[0];
});
```

`json_encode` result:

```
[["2016","0000-00-00"],["2017","0000-00-00"],["2018","0000-00-00"]]
```

Now I need to sort items by descending order having this result:

```
[["2018","0000-00-00"],["2017","0000-00-00"],["2016","0000-00-00"]]
```

I tried to change  `return $a[0] <=> $b[0];` into this:

```
 return $a[0] > $b[0];
 return $a[0] < $b[0];
 return $a[0] - $b[0];
 return $b[0] <=> $a[0];
```

Nothing works. Any help?

Comment: How about `$b[0] <=> $a[0]`? (Switched `a` and `b`).

Comment: @RomanHocke - also tried

Comment: Please show exact code that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (used `$b[0] <=> $a[0]` for sorting):

```
$array = json_decode('[["2016","0000-00-00"],["2017","0000-00-00"],["2018","0000-00-00"]]', TRUE);
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $b[0] <=> $a[0]; });
print_r($array);
```

The result is sorted descending:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2018
        [1] => 0000-00-00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2017
        [1] => 0000-00-00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2016
        [1] => 0000-00-00
    )
```

Comment: seems something else is problem with my code. Anyway thanks a lot. Let's say - solved.

Answer (score 1):

`$a[0] < $b[0]` works for me.

```php
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
     return $a[0] < $b[0];
});
```

[Live demo here](https://3v4l.org/1Lcrk)